# Import CSV file in MySQL : How to get log and bad files?

Tags: mysql

If I want to import `CSV file` to `Oracle`, i use this script :

```
sqlldr user/pass@host data=test.csv control=ctl\test.ctl log=log\test.log bad=bad\test.bad
```

Log import and bad data will saved in test.log and test.bad files.

If I want to import `CSV file` to `Mysql`, i use this script :

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE abc 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

How to get log import and bad data file?

Answer (score 1):

```
`load data local infile 'C:\\temp\\abc.csv'
into table table_name
fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines 
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4)
set 
table.column_name = @col1,
table.column_name = @col2,
table.column_name = @col3,
table.column_name = @col4;`
```

---

> ***@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4 are your CSV file columns, set them against your table columns as shown above***

---

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. How about log of import report and bad files?

Comment: Hi Priyanshu. iam confused. what different between (@col1,...) and (col1,...). why use @ symbol?